# sudoku check terms

Tags: python, sudoku

I need to check if the number the user insert is already in the colum, row or "block" (still working on the last part).
for some reason these checks don't work and I don't get why?
I wrote the same code in the shell and it worked just fine.

my code:

```
def is_valid_move(board,row, column, digit):
    if digit in board[row]:
        print "Row already contains", digit
        return (False)
    else:
        return (True)

    for i in range(9):
        if digit in board[i][row]:
            print "Colum already contains", digit
            return (False)
            break
        else:
            return (True)

board = [[3,7,0,0,5,0,0,0,0],
         [0,6,0,0,3,0,2,0,0],
         [0,2,9,4,0,0,0,7,8],
         [0,0,4,1,7,0,0,8,0],
         [0,0,6,3,0,5,9,0,0],
         [0,5,0,0,8,4,1,0,0],
         [7,1,0,0,0,8,5,6,0],
         [0,0,5,0,1,0,0,2,0],
         [0,0,0,0,9,0,0,1,3]]

a=is_valid_move(board,1, 2, 9)
print a
```

output I get:

```
True
```

---

any idea how to check if number is already in the box?

Thanks!

Comment: What doesn't work? I see that your for loop would never execute.

Comment: python print True, I guess its result of some previous checks for other stuff. anyway it just print 'True'

Comment: Please don’t change the code to a fixed code later because that will basically make the answers useless (as they refer to the original code).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you return true, as soon as you find any check that does not fail. So if you have a valid row, your check is already successful, although the column could be full with the same number.

So basically, remove all `return True` lines and put a single one at the very end after all checks are over.

Also a few more things:

- Don’t put parentheses around `True` or `False` in your returns.
- You don’t need to `break` after `return` as the latter will already end the function.
- `board[i][row]` evaluates in a single digit, so a check with `digit in` will not work as it expects an iterable.
- `board[i][row]` should be `board[i][column]` as the first list index is already the row.

To check if the third condition for a 3x3 group is valid, you first need to identify which “box” a cell belongs to, and then check all the numbers inside:

```py
# get the first row/column index of a block
blockRow = row // 3 * 3
blockColumn = column // 3 * 3

# check all 8 fields in the block
for r in range(blockRow, blockRow + 3):
    for c in range(blockColumn, blockColumn + 3):
        # skip the field we want to check
        if r == row and c == column:
            continue

        if digit == board[r][c]:
            return False
```

Comment: tnx!
it helped, but only the first term.
now the second term give an error.
"if digit in board[i][row]:
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable"

Comment: `board[i][row]` is a single number, so you cannot check `digit in single_numer` but need to check for equality: `digit == board[i][row]`.

Comment: I think `blockRow = row` should be `blockRow = row - (row % 3)`. The same for `blockColumn`.

Comment: @MohamedA. The syntax highlighter is displaying that not correctly, the `// 3 * 3` part is part of it. It’s an integer division and then multiplication by 3. Basically the same as yours with the modulo operator.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I forgot it was python code and thought `// 3*3` was a comment :)

Comment: Okay, I finally got the highlighter to display that correctly…

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create a sudoku for the users take this tips the way to remove the numbers its in mirror mode (sorry for my english) example

(1 _ 3 4)

```
        (7 _ 5 6)
```

Comment: what?
Im looking for solution how to check if the number is in the box already